# Simplify git routine 'fast cherrypick to another branch'

Tags: git

I have two branches in my repository: 'stable' and 'master'.
Sometimes I should fix a bug in 'stable' and cherrypick it to 'master' branch.
For that I must to do several steps: switch to 'master', find a commit & cherrypick it after that I must switch back to 'stable' to fix next bug.
How can I simplify this routine?
Whether it is possible?

Comment: Git is very scriptable. Have you considered writing a script to make this faster?

Comment: Yes, it's a variant, but I think about existent one, so I write down here. :-)
In hope that maybe somebody knows existent approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can type it into the command line, you can script it:

```
git checkout master && git cherry-pick stable && git checkout stable
```

Note: `git cherry-pick stable` will cherry-pick the commit that's at the TIP of the stable branch.

If you want a more general function:

```
#An alias so we can get the current branch with `git current-branch`
git config --global alias.current-branch 'symbolic-ref --short HEAD'

git-cherry-pick-onto() {
   local original_branch=`git current-branch`

   git checkout "$1" &&\
   git cherry-pick "$original_branch" &&\
   git checkout "$original_branch"
}
```

And then you can do (from stable):

```
git-cherry-pick-onto master
```

and that will cherry-pick the latest commit in the current branch onto master (or whatever branch you provide as the argument).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if your branches are much different, repetitive checkouting on another branch can be unbearable.

You may add local copy of your repository and always keep it looking on **master** branch while your original repo is always looking on **stable** branch.

All you need in this scenario to switch between repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can cherry-pick several commit `git cherry-pick 18795aedbc 5415dfeacb ...`, i suggest to correct all your bug with the commit and cherry pick all the commits at the end.

Comment: Yes, I know about this feature, but it doesn't approach for my scenario, because after each bugfix I must send my results to testers.
Anyway thank you!